# SQLite query: between

Tags: android, sqlite, between

I am using SQLit in my Android app, I want to search in my database.

my query and error is this :

```
              Error Code : 1 (SQLITE_ERROR)
              Caused By : SQL(query) error or missing database.
                near "to": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling:
select * from informations where house_type = 'آپارتمانی' and room_count = '1' and (cost between 0 to 100000000) and (area between 0 to 1000)
```

anybody knows what is the problem ?

Comment: If you have trouble getting an SQLite query working, it often helps to eliminate variables, e.g. the programming language and other parts of the environment. To do so I like using the  minimal environment of the SQLite commandline tool. It also is helpful for making a good [mcve] for StackOverflow, via the offered `.dump` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax for the BETWEEN operator is `test_expression BETWEEN low_expression AND high_expression`. So change `TO` in `AND`.